# Cricket stumps that don't need to be pushed into the ground

Tags: cricket, equipment

I'm looking for a set of cricket stumps that don't need to be pushed into the ground or some other way to use the traditional set of cricket stumps on a hard surface such as a tennis court.

Anybody have any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is to get the kind of stumps used in indoor cricket. You can see some in use for instance [here](http://www.sportsworldindoor.com.au/peakhurst/graphics/headers/indoor-cricket-rules.jpg). The stumps are connected to a flat solid base and are spring loaded so they return to the upright positions by themselves after being knocked over by the ball.

I'm sure these could be purchased online if you can't find any at your local sports stores.